# how do i create a function to change header banner when using jquery tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors, tabs

i have 3 default jquery tabs loading external content.

However i need the following adding/binding and was wondering if someone can help me with this issue;

1. Aswell as loading each tabs content, i need a different header banner to display (outsude of the tab countainer..so i basically have an id called #bannerAd) when each tab is selected.
2. the coding should be set so a user can link directly to each tab from outside the page (and each banner should load acordingly.)

I really hope this makes sense, hope someone can help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    // Tabs
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
    );

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Tabs -->
    <h2 class="demoHeaders"></h2>
    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also put data- attributes one each of your tabs.

```
<li><a href="#tabs-1" data-bannerurl="banner1.png">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2" data-bannerurl="banner2.png">Second</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3" data-bannerurl="banner3.png">Third</a></li>
```

Then in your jQuery

```
$("#tabs li a").click(function() {
    var bannerUrl = $(this).data().bannerurl;
    $("#bannerAd").attr("src", bannerUrl);
});
```

Live in action here: http://jsbin.com/iquluz/5/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: that seems good, but its not displaying the banners when i compile the page. ..not showing errors though :s

Comment: Just updated w/ a live in action snippet, http://jsbin.com/iquluz/3/edit. Let me know if u have any q's about the code u find on there.

Comment: thats great Ian, however i need the banner to auto oad whatever tab you are currently one, right now the <img id="bannerAd" src="http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/16/12/11161270_mob.jpg" /> shows, but i need to have it load which ever default tab is loaded....hope that makes sense.

Comment: you can leave it `<img id="bannerAd" src="" />` initially, and do something like this: `var defaultBannerUrl = $(".ui-tabs-selected > a").data().bannerurl; $("#bannerAd").attr("src", defaultBannerUrl);` after your .tabs() call, illustrated here http://jsbin.com/iquluz/5/edit

Comment: and then as you change it by clicking the tabs, the banner ad changes. so that your banner ad reflects whatever tab the user is currently on. this is all in the latest jsbin link.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be the easiest thing:

```
$("#tabs li a").click(function() {

switch($("this").attr("href")) {

case "#tabs-1":
//Load First Banner
break;

case "#tabs-2":
//Load Second Banner
break;

case "#tabs-3":
//Load Third Banner
break;

}

});
```

This will basically set up a click event on the buttons that will fire whenever any of them get clicked.  It will then figure out which button was clicked and change the banner accordingly.

And you'd want to put it in your `$(function()`